# OBJ appears in view of the Application

Tags: android, cardview

I am making an RSS Feed App and [OBJ] appears in view. I am trimming out HTML coding from the RSS feed. using this line (This started happening after I added this line. thats why I suspect that's my problem. sicne without that line it does not happen)

```
item.setDescription(Html.fromHtml(current.getTextContent()).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim());
```

Here is an image of what I am seeing (i have blured out the content just left the obj block that appears)  I think this appears only when its replacing an Image

[image]

How do I remove this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found out how to fix this. " OBJ inside a box means the program interpreted whatever it was as the Unicode object replacement character (U65532). "

So Ill I had to do was Trim that when it appears. as I show bellow. I hope this helps others in the future.

```
stringname.replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim()
```